# Should variables always be declared with interface in Java?

Tags: java, list, declaration

One often sees the advice that variables should be declared with some interface, not the implementing class. For example:

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, say I am using this list for an algorithm that really depended on the O(1) random access of an `ArrayList` (e.g. Fisher-Yates shuffling). In that case, the key abstraction that `ArrayList` represents for me is its array-like nature, not just its List nature. In other words, if someone came along and changed `list` to a `LinkedList`, this would be problematic, even though the code would compile. In such a case, is it considered ok to have the declaration use the implementation type?, e.g.:

```
ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: Unless you're exposing the List/ArrayList reference via a public API, it really doesn't matter (as in all other cases, a modern IDE should make it trivial to refactor one type to another).  So do whatever is most convenient.

Comment: Depending on the size of the data you're expecting, you could accept a List<T> and then copy it into an ArrayList inside your function to guarantee random access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To emphasize what Oliver Charlesworth said in the comment: The most crucial difference whether this information is public or not.

From the way how the question is written, it seems like you're talking about a *field* (and not a method parameter or return value). And a private field is, per definition, an implementation detail, and you *may* make it arbitrarily specific. So it would be feasible to declare it as an `ArrayList` - although, strictly speaking, this is not relevant. To phrase it that way: You said

> if someone ... changed `list` to a `LinkedList`, this would be problematic,...

The one who can change the declaration from

```
private List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

to

```
private List<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
```

can also change the declaration from

```
private ArrayList<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

to

```
private LinkedList<T> list = new LinkedList<T>();
```

The only practical way to prevent this would be to add this (important) implementation detail as a comment, e.g.

```
/**
 * The list that stores ... whatever. 
 *
 * This list should have a complexity of O(1) for random access,
 * because ...
 */
private final List<T> list = new ArrayList<T>();
```

(This could also be enforced by internally passing the list to a method that expects it to be a `RandomAccess`. This was proposed by AlexR, but referring to `public` methods. For `private` methods, even this won't prevent someone from changing the method signature, if the *intention* and the *reasons* for requiring `RandomAccess` are not documented).

Comment: What do you mean "strictly speaking, this is not relevant"?

Comment: @PeteyPabPro I mean that declaring the list as `ArrayList` does not bring any benefit. Everybody who can change the type of the *instance* that is created there can also change the type of the *variable*. (Note that it does not bring a benefit, but a potential (minor) drawback, namely that you also have to change the declaration of the variable when you want to change the *instance* from `ArrayList` to any other list that has O(1). For example, you could also use a `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, which is *not* an `ArrayList`, but still has O(1) and thus would be OK here)

Comment: I see two benefits. 1) Serves as a form of documentation, and 2) If someone, for whatever reason, wanted to do some automated refactoring to switch instances of List from ArrayList to LinkedList, having the variable declared as ArrayList would prevent the developer from unknowingly breaking the O(1) requirement.

Comment: As I said: You *may* make it specific, but it's more important to *document* something like this. I never heard of such a refactoring pattern, though...

Answer (score 2):

I think that using interfaces is still very important. You case is very special but there is a way to solve it without usage of concrete classes. There is interface named `RandomAccess`. It is tag interface that does not declare methods but it should be used by implementors or `List` that do provide randome access to elements.

So, you can define your method that requires random access list as following:

```
public <E, L extends List<E> & RandomAcess>void algorithm(L list);
```

You will not be able to pass linked list to this method, but `ArrayList` will work. As you an expect now you can change implemtation of list without changing your algorithm. For example you can use thread safe `CopyOnWriteArrayList` that will allow yo to make you processing multithreaded without explicit `syncrhonized` statements.

Comment: But the list I pass to this will have to have declared type `ArrayList`, not `List`, so it doesn't seem to allow me to avoid concrete classes for the declaration.

Comment: It is OK that you pass `ArrayList` to your method. But if method is defined as I suggested you can change the type of list that you pass without changing the method.